# Linq with Entity Framework and Automapper - populate field with a value

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using an Automapper extension to populate a DTO directly from Entity Framework - which is working nicely.  However, what I want to do is to update a field with a common value for each record returned.

I've been able to acheive this by just re-iterating the list and updating the field after the list has been mapped.

I want to know if there is a more efficent way of doing this.  I'm thinking currently I am iterating the collection twice and want to know if I can do it all in one go AND without having to use select => into a new class because I then have map every field.  I will be using this is a pattern as it will be used everywhere and dont want to have to individually map every field (unless you can use select without having to map every field).

```
public async Task<List<JobPositionDto>> GetJobPositions(string region, string prefix, string jobId)
    {
        string connString = _configuration.GetCountryFromPrefix(region, prefix).DatabaseConnectionString;
        _context.ChangeConnectionString(connString);

        var jobPositions = await _context.JobPositions
            .ProjectTo<JobPositionDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .Where(x => x.jobId == jobId)
            .OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo)
            .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var jobPosition in jobPositions)
        {
            jobPosition.Prefix = prefix;
        }

        return jobPositions;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not with a centralized Automapper configuration. One option would be to treat your mapper configuration more situationally. As an example this is one option I use to organize automapper configuration by letting the destination models determine their mapping needs (Extracted from one of my projects):

```
[Serializable]
public class DayPartViewModel
{
    public int DayPartId { get; set; }
    public string DayPartGroup { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RawStartTime { get; set; }
    public int RawEndTime { get; set; }
    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return TimeFormatter.ToString(RawStartTime); }
    }
    public string EndTime
    {
        get { return TimeFormatter.ToString(RawEndTime); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an automapper configuration for populating this view model
    /// from its associated entity.
    /// </summary>
    public static MapperConfigurationExpression BuildMapperConfig(MapperConfigurationExpression config = null)
    {
        if (config == null)
            config = new MapperConfigurationExpression();

        config.CreateMap<DayPart, DayPartViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.DayPartGroup, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DayPartGroup.Name))
            .ForMember(x => x.RawStartTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartTime))
            .ForMember(x => x.RawEndTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndTime));
        config.CreateMap<DayPart, SelectListItem>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(x => x.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DayPartId));

        return config;
    }
}
```

Then when I would want to read DayParts via ProjectTo:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(DayPartViewModel.BuildMapperConfig);

using (var contextScope = ContextScopeFactory.CreateReadOnly())
{
    var dayParts = LookupRepository.GetDayParts()
        .ProjectTo<DayPartViewModel>(config)
        .ToList(); 
    // ...
}
```

The BuildMapperConfig can be chained so if there are multiple related entities the top level entity can initialize mapper and pass that mapper configuration through to each child view model BuildMapperConfig to append to.

With something like this your BuildMapperConfig could include an optional "prefix" to use for a mapping expression:

```
public static MapperConfigurationExpression BuildMapperConfig(MapperConfigurationExpression config = null, string? prefix = null)
```

Then within the config:

```
.ForMember(x => x.Prefix, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => prefix))
```

assuming Prefix is always going to be populated by the value provided.

This is something you could introduce side-by-side to use instead of `_mapper.ConfigurationProvider`, just document that it is to facilitate situational mapping.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization